# Как сверстать пунктирную линию между двумя частями текста?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap

Имеется следующий код:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <p class="catalog-item__characteristics">
            Диагональ: <br>
            Количество SIM-карт: <br>
            Камера: <br>
            Ёмкость аккумулятора: <br>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-5">
        <p class="catalog-item__characteristics">
            6 дюймов <br>
            2 <br>
            48 МП, 8 МП, 16 МПМпикс <br>
            4000 мА⋅чмАч <br>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Между двумя частями текста, левой и правой, необходимо выполнить такую пунктирную линию:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это сделать?
JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rdzqgpjw/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.catalog-items__characteristics p{
 position: relative;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
.catalog-items__characteristics p:after{
 content: '';
 height: 10px;
 width: 100%;
 background-image: radial-gradient(#ebebeb 40%, transparent 50%);
 background-size: 10px 10px;
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 background-position: 0 center;
 display: block;
 margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
     <div class="col-6 catalog-items__characteristics">
   <p>Диагональ</p>
   <p>Количество SIM-карт</p>
   <p>Камера</p>
   <p>Ёмкость аккумулятора</p>
     </div>
  <div class="col-5">
   <p>6 дюймов</p>
   <p>2</p>
   <p>48 МП, 8 МП, 16 МПМпикс</p>
   <p>4000 мА⋅чмАч</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Как вариант с использованием **radial-gradient**

Answer (score 0):

Используй свойство `stroke-dasharray:# #2, где`#`будет управлять длиной отрезков,`#2` — длиной пробелов.